# For each loop, update variable

Tags: python, for-loop

I have an assignment where I have to implement code stubs. A simplified version basically is:

```
for a,b in zip(var_a,var_b):
   # implementation here
```

I'm pretty sure the task is basically  to update a with the variable b. But this would be very weird because my understanding is that a,b are just copies of var_a,var_b. So changing the values of a,b won't affect var_a,var_b.
Am I right?

Of course, I could easily change the code, so I really update var_a,var_b but I don't think changing the stubs is intended, which would either mean the stub was poorly designed or I didn't understand the task correctly.

Could you please confirm that in this for loop I only have access to the copies or is there a suuper easy way to update the original variables without changing the stub?

Comment: If the elements of `var_a`, `var_b` are mutable, then you could mutate them by applying appropriate operations to `a` or `b`.  But *assigning* to `a` or `b` has no effect on the original objects, they're just local variables here.

Comment: You might try `for i, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(var_a, var_b))`. If `var_b` is indexable, this lets you use `b` instead of `var_b[i]` where convenient, but also lets you assign back `var_b` where necessary. (I.e., `var_b[i] = a*b`).

Comment: Yeah I know this trick but changing the stub feels wrong

Answer (score 1):

a and b aren't copy of var_a and var_b, but rather they point to the first element in var_a and var_b respectively.

About changing their value - you can do it, but of course if you just reassign them it will not affect var_a or var_b.
So if they are mutable - that's not the way to do it.

but for example, if var_a and var_b are list of lists, you can do something like:
a.extend(b). And it will affect the list in var_a.

Read about [objects mutability in python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mutable-vs-immutable-objects-in-python/#:~:text=Immutable%20Objects%20%3A%20These%20are%20of,changed%20after%20it%20is%20created.&text=Mutable%20Objects%20%3A%20These%20are%20of,Custom%20classes%20are%20generally%20mutable.).

```
>>> var_a = [[1,2,3],[10,20,30]]
>>> var_b = [['a','b','c'], ['A','B','C']]
>>> for a, b in zip(var_a, var_b):
...  a.extend(b)
...
>>> var_a
[[1, 2, 3, 'a', 'b', 'c'], [10, 20, 30, 'A', 'B', 'C']]
```

but integers are immutable:

```
>>> var_a = [1,2,3]
>>> var_b = [10,20,30]
>>> for a, b in zip(var_a, var_b):
...  a += b
...
>>> var_a
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Interesting I didn't know that. a and b will be in fact numpy arrays, but I'm supposed to do in place updating